# Python - no connection adapters were found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this frustrating problem which I don't know how to fix. I wanted to test that script to download something from ftp server:

```
import requests
import sys
import time

def downloadFile(url, directory) :
  localFilename = url.split('/')[-1]
  print(url)
  with open(directory + '/' + localFilename, 'wb') as f:
    start = time.clock()
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    total_length = r.headers.get('content-length')
    dl = 0
    if total_length is None: # no content length header
      f.write(r.content)
    else:
      for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
        dl += len(chunk)
        f.write(chunk)
        done = int(50 * dl / total_length)
        sys.stdout.write("\r[%s%s] %s bps" % ('=' * done, ' ' * (50-done), dl//(time.clock() - start)))
        print("")
  return (time.clock() - start)

def main() :
  if len(sys.argv) > 1 :
        url = sys.argv[1]
  else :
        url = input("Enter the URL : ")
  directory = input("Where would you want to save the file ?")

  time_elapsed = downloadFile(url, directory)
  print( "Download complete...")
  print ("Time Elapsed: " + time_elapsed)


if __name__ == "__main__" :
  main()
```

Url I use is ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Datasets/CHDI/CHR2010_051010.xlsx but when I run it there comes the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Pigeon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 731, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Datasets/CHDI/CHR2010_051010.xlsx'
```

Anyone knows why it happens?
Thanks for reply

Comment: I think what it means is that `requests` has no means to speak the protocol specified in the url, i.e. the `FTP` protocol. Normally it is used to speak `http`

Comment: Requests does not support FTP on its own. But there are adapter for it available on Pypi.

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that `requests` has no means to speak the protocol specified in the url, i.e. `FTP`. Normally it is used to speak `HTTP`.

In a URL (URI really), the `scheme` specifies the protocol to be used for the dialog.

In your case it's `FTP`, as the prefix of the URI says `ftp://`

Please have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) for a good breakdown of the components that form a URI and their meaning.

There are specific libraries to "speak" FTP (File Transfer Protocol)

e.g. the standard [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html)

but in case you want/need to use `requests`, you can try using [requests-ftp](https://pypi.org/project/requests-ftp/).

As it says, it provides an FTP transport adapter to the `requests` library.